# How can I manually propagate a value to the directive's parent scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

My AngularJS typeahead `FaveDirective` needs to bind a single value to the parent scope, and call an update function when that value changes:

Parent html:

```
<div class="parent-controller-scope ng-scope">
  <my-fave-picker favorite="parent.favorite" on-change="parent.update()">
</div>
```

Fave picker directive template:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="vm.favorite" 
    typeahead-on-select="vm.onChange()"
    ng-init="vm.loadTypeaheadValues()"
    placeholder="Pick your favorite Swift"
    uib-typeahead="name for name in ::vm.TypeaheadValues | filter:$viewValue"
    class="form-control">
```

Fave picker directive code:

```
(function (angular, _) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('favorite')
        .directive('MyFavePicker', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'fave-picker-template.html',
                scope: {
                    favorite: '=',
                    onChange: '&'
                },
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                bindToController: true,
                controller: 'FavePickerController'
            };
        })
        .controller('FavePickerController', function() {
             // etc.
        });

}(angular, _));
```

This works almost correctly; when the typeahead input is committed, it calls `update()` on the parent scope as intended. The problem is that this happens *before* the latest value of `favorite` is propagated to the parent scope. In other words, if the typeahead has possible values `["Taylor Swift", "Jonathan Swift"]` and I type "Tay" and then hit enter to select the value from the dropdown, then at the time the `typeahead-on-select` callback is executed, I have the following values:

```
vm.favorite = "Taylor Swift"    
parent.favorite = "Tay"
```

The `parent.update()` function therefore operates with the wrong value of `parent.favorite` ("Tay" instead of "Taylor Swift").

I can think of some bad ways, but what's the right way to do this so that the change to `vm.favorite` gets propagated back to the parent scope *before* calling `parent.favorite()`?

Note that the following things are not possible in my circumstances:

- inheriting parent scope instead of using isolate scope
- passing `favorite` as an argument to `update` (`on-change="parent.update(favorite)"`)
- setting a timeout in `dir.onChange()` before calling `parent.update()`

Comment: You mention Angular (aka Angular 2 and 4) and you tag with AngularJS (aka Angular 1.x). Which one is it?

Comment: According to the code shown, it seems to be AngularJS

Comment: Sorry for the confusion -- it's AngularJS (1.x). Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using two-way, `'='`, binding in components to propagate values. Instead use one-way, `'<'`, binding for inputs and expression, `'&'`, binding for outputs:

```
<my-fave-picker  favorite="parent.favorite"
    on-change="parent.favorite=$value; parent.update($value)">
</my-fave-picker>
```

```
app.directive('MyFavePicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'fave-picker-template.html',
        scope: {
            ̶f̶a̶v̶o̶r̶i̶t̶e̶:̶ ̶'̶=̶'̶,̶ 
            favorite: '<',
            onChange: '&'
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'FavePickerController'
    };
})
```

In the component template:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="vm.favorite"
    ng-change="vm.onChange({$value: vm.favorite})"
    typeahead-on-select="vm.onChange({$value: vm.favorite})"
    ng-init="vm.loadTypeaheadValues()"
    placeholder="Pick your favorite Swift"
    uib-typeahead="name for name in ::vm.TypeaheadValues | filter:$viewValue"
    class="form-control"
/>
```

By applying the value in the expression, `'&'`, binding, the value is propagated immediately. With two-way, `'='`, binding, the value is propagated after a digest cycle.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component Based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)